# Tableview cell subtitles not showing or the app quits

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

My tableview cell subtitles aren't showing when I use this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell?

    if tableView.tag == 1 {

        guard let latestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell") else {
            return UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "latestCell")
        }



        latestCell.textLabel?.text = latest[indexPath.row]

        latestCell.detailTextLabel?.text = latestSub[indexPath.row]

        latestCell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        return latestCell


    }
}
```

But then if I use this:

```
else if tableView.tag == 2 {

        let olderCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "olderCell")



        olderCell.textLabel?.text = older[indexPath.row]

        olderCell.detailTextLabel?.text = olderSub[indexPath.row]

        olderCell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

        return olderCell
    }

    else {
        return cell!
    }
}
```

The subtitles load perfectly, but after I close the app and reload the view, the app autoquits without giving a crash log or taking me to the debugging-tab.

I know that the arrays from which the data comes from are fine, and I think that I've set up everything right in the storyboard. A lot of similar questions have already been posted on the subject, but they all seem to come down to forgetting to set the cellStyle to .subtitle. Thanks in advance for any help I get!

BTW. My regular cell titles are working just like I want them to. No problem there.

Answer (score 1):

In your first section, your guard statement is returning before you've set the cell's text and detail text. If you changed it to:

```
if let latestCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell") {
    cell = latestCell            
} else {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "latestCell")
}             
cell.textLabel?.text = latest[indexPath.row]

cell.detailTextLabel?.text = latestSub[indexPath.row]

cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

return cell
```

The labels will now get set.

And your crash is caused by this:

```
 return cell!
```

If cell == nil, then cell! will attempt to unwrap it. And really, what you should be doing is calling super's implementation:

```
return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
```

Good luck.

Comment: I wasn't able to return the super.tableview, Xcode won't allow it. Other than that I changed the code and it still doesn't show the subtitles, but it's not crashing either. Thanks for replying though!

Comment: Do you have anything to add or another solution?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back sooner. It looks like it should work -- maybe set a breakpoint after `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = latestSub[indexPath.row]` and then type `p cell.detailTextLabel?.text` in lldb to see if it's actually set correctly. While you're at it type `p latestSub[indexPath.row]` to see if your array got populated correctly.

Comment: Also check the settings in your storyboard, for instance make sure the tableview's Content is Dynamic Prototypes and not Static Cells.

Also double check that there aren't any Auto Layout issues on your table cells (you'll see a tiny yellow arrow next to an offending scene in the scenes list on your storyboard) This is usually automagically handled by Xcode, but I've accidentally messed things up.